# AVPlayer live radio streaming stop after 15 minutes or so

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, avplayer

As the title, I'm trying to live stream internet radio on both **iOS** and **OS X** using `AVPlayer` instance. Everything works as expected with a simple `player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:URL];`

While using the app, I noticed that the stream just stop after 15 minutes, give or take a few. The problem is that no noticed was given.

```
[player addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"status" options:0 context:nil];
[player addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"rate" options:0 context:nil];

- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {
    if (object == player) {
        if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"status"]) {
            NSLog(@"status -> %ld", player.status);
        }
        if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"rate"]) {
            NSLog(@"rate -> %f", player.rate);
        }
    }
}
```

Both values switched to `1` but never switch again even the audio is stop playing. on iOS the *play* icon on top right is gone but the app still think there's audio playing due to the player.rate value doesn't change.

First I thought it was the stream, so I tried other streams from 5by5 and twit, same thing happen.

Then I thought it was my connection, so after the stream started, I turn off my connection, after a minute or so, `AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification` I observed is fired.

Took awhile to test this.

So any idea why is this happening? And more importantly, how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I noticed that the `player.currentTime` is stuck while `player.rate` is **1**. So at least on OS X I can track it and restart the stream if stuck.

```
2013-04-30 12:49:07.730 Radio[60315:303] rate -> 1.000000
2013-04-30 12:49:07.731 Radio[60315:303] status -> 1
2013-04-30 13:09:04.154 Radio[60315:303] Stuck at 1195 x 1
2013-04-30 13:09:05.155 Radio[60315:303] Stuck at 1195 x 2
2013-04-30 13:09:06.155 Radio[60315:303] Stuck at 1195 x 3
2013-04-30 13:09:07.155 Radio[60315:303] >> Stuck! Restart stream <<
2013-04-30 13:09:09.426 Radio[60315:303] rate -> 1.000000
2013-04-30 13:09:09.426 Radio[60315:303] status -> 1
```

Comment: Nice work around!  I believe there's a problem with AVPlayer, as when the stuck happens, the AVPlayer's periodic observer won't get fired anymore.